# Get the ip address of the request in ninja framework

Tags: scala, akka, spray, ninjaframework

I have the following frameworks in my app

```
Ninja, Akka, Spray
```

How do I get the client's request's ip address ?

My routing is defined as follows:

```
    router.GET.route(urlPrefix + "/method").`with`(classOf[Controller],"method")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether your question refers to [www.ninjaframework.org](http://www.ninjaframework.org/) or [spray.io](http://spray.io/), but if you're using the former, you can get the remote IP address in your controller method:

```
public Result method(Context context) {
    String ip = context.getRemoteAddr();
    // ...
}
```

As the documentation states (http://www.ninjaframework.org/apidocs/ninja/Context.html#getRemoteAddr--), you have to set the `ninja.ninja.x_forwarded_for_enabled` flag to `true` in your application.conf if your app is running behind a http proxy or load balancer.